# vuex push into nested array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm trying to add an object to a nested array but am not sure how to achieve this using store / vuex. I have no problems updating the main comments array using a mutation but am stuck on how to specify which main comment to push the new reply object to. The pushReply mutations adds the reply to EVERY instance of a comment.

VUEX:

```
export const state = () => ({
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      likes: 0,
      postDate: '12/22/2021 1:25pm',
      name: 'amyrobson',
      img: '/img/avatars/image-amyrobson.png',
      post: `Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved.
              But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the
              responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.`,

      replies: [
        {
          id: 1,
          likes: 0,
          postDate: '12/22/2021 1:25pm',
          name: 'Reply One',
          img: '/img/avatars/image-avatar.png',
          post: `Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam a aut quis
                recusandae magnam tenetur porro autem minima aspernatur
                voluptatum`,
        },
    
      ],
    },
  ],
})

export const mutations = {
  pushComment(state, comment) {
    state.comments.push(comment)
  },


    pushReply(state, comment) {
      state.comments.forEach((item) => {
      item.replies.push(comment)
    })
  },
    }
```

component:

```
methods: {
    addComment() {
      this.isSending = true

      // postDate
      const newDate = new Date()
      const currentDate = newDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US')
      const currentTime = newDate.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        timeStyle: 'short',
      })
      const createdAt = `${currentDate} ${currentTime}`

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$store.commit('comments/pushComment', {
          id: this.$store.state.comments.comments.length + 1,
          likes: 0,
          postDate: createdAt,
          name: 'ramsesmiron',
          img: this.image,
          post: this.formValues.comment,
          replies: [],
        })
        this.$formulate.reset('formAddComment')
        this.isSending = false
      }, 1000)
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify on which comment you want to add this reply object.
Either by passing the comment id to `pushReply` or by adding this id to the reply object (like `parentId`).
Then, in the `pushReply` function, find the comment by this id and add this reply to it.

You have several ways as this one:

```js
const state = {
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      replies: [],
      parentId: null,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      replies: [],
      parentId: null,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      replies: [],
      parentId: null,
    },
  ],
};

const reply = {
  id: 1,
  replies: [],
  parentId: 2,
};

function pushReply(state, comment) {
  if (null === comment.parentId) return; // handle this case, maybe throw an error
  state.comments.find((item, i) => {
    if (item.id === comment.parentId) {
      state.comments[i].replies.push(comment);
    }
  });
}

pushReply(state, reply);
console.log(state);
```